# Why is Heroku installing old Python (pip) dependencies in new deployments?

Tags: python, django, heroku

(Asking here as directed by Heroku's own support)

We have just uncovered a dependency issue in a project with mismatched libraries between dev environments. The details aren't relevant, but the underlying cause was a dependency that had a ">=" version match in its `setup.py` - which meant that when a dev rebuilt his environment he suddenly got the latest version (0.4.0) instead of the old version he'd had previously (0.3.11), and started getting a `DeprecationWarning`.

As part of the debugging process, I was under the impression that whenever a repo is pushed to Heroku, a clean environment is rebuilt, which led me to assume, incorrectly, that our DEV environment (which is rebuilt daily) would have had the latest version installed. Because we *weren't* seeing the issue on the dev environment I decided to investigate, and ran `heroku run pip list` on the remote environment.

I was (very) surprised to see that the output of this was a lucky dip of old and expired dependencies, and **not** a clean environment at all. It turns out that we may have had the issue that we were debugging living happily on our live environment, as part of an old install.

The easiest way to explain this is the BeautifulSoup library. We recently updated from v3 to v4, and as part of this, the library itself changed name on PyPI from `BeautifulSoup` to `beautifulsoup4`. We updated out `requirements.txt` to reflect this, but if I now run `pip list` on our Heroku environment I get both:

```
~ $ heroku run bash
~ $ pip list
BeautifulSoup (3.2.1)
beautifulsoup4 (4.3.2)
```

So, the old dependency hasn't been cleared, it's just sitting there. I can prove it easily enough by firing up a python session:

```
~ $ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 22:14:13)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bs4
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>>
```

This is a bit of a shock, and I'm amazed that this hasn't killed off our application at some point?

So, the question is - how does Heroku manage dependencies under the hood - it obviously doesn't wipe the python environment and re-run `pip install` on each deployment - and is there any way I can force this behaviour?

[EDIT 1]

FWIW, this is the buildpack that does the install - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/compile

[EDIT 2]

From the [Heroku Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api) docs:

> The contents of CACHE_DIR will be persisted between builds. You can cache the results of long processes like dependency resolution here to speed up future builds.

And [further down](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api#caching):

> The bin/compile script will be given a CACHE_DIR as its second argument which can be used to store artifacts between builds. Artifacts stored in this directory will be available in the CACHE_DIR during successive builds. CACHE_DIR is available only during slug compilation, and is specific to the app being built.

The recommendation is:

> Heroku users can use the heroku-repo plugin to clear the build cache created by the buildpack they use for their app

That said - whilst I understand that the cache is used to speed up future compilations, I don't understand why everything in the cache is installed. That doesn't make any sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku installs your Python environment in `/app/.heroku/python` and the entire `.heroku` directory gets copied in from the CACHE_DIR at the beginning of each build and then back to the CACHE_DIR at the end. (If you search for `restore_cache` and `dump_cache` in that buildpack script you'll see the lines that do this.)

So once you've installed something in your Heroku app, there it stays unless the CACHE_DIR somehow gets wiped. Obviously this isn't ideal, but it was done to avoid the very long build times that would result from recompiling and installing all your dependencies on every deploy. (For what it's worth, I think there's now a better way of achieving this using wheels to cache compiled packages so you can get a fresh environment every time without having to wait for everything to rebuild. I might try to put together an example and poke Kenneth Reitz about it.)

In the immediate term, it sounds like you would benefit from explicitly pinning the versions of all your dependencies (which include dependencies of dependencies and so on). Simply running `pip freeze > requirements.txt` would be a good start, although you might also want to look at [pip-tools](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools). You really want to avoid the situation you just described where a dev rebuilds their environment from `requirements.txt` and ends up with a different version of a package.

As for BeautifulSoup changing their package name (but not, presumably, the name of the module you import) that sounds really horrible, and exactly the sort of situation in which Heroku's caching breaks down! I think the only solution would be to use that heroku-repo plugin and nuke your cache entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. We did run for a long time using the full pinning, but then got caught with a mismatch between a dependency of a dependency and our pinned version. Using `heroko_repo` and `purge_cache` did at least clear down the environment, and allow us to find out what was really going on. It's as much about housekeeping as anything - having old deps that we no longer rely on cleared out of the environment.

Comment: PS if you are poking KR about buildpacks - this one also tripped us up (as part of debugging this) - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/pull/152